# Fiddler is not capturing the any browser traffic and showing me this error

Tags: fiddler, fiddler-everywhere

I just changed my VPN and tried to capture the browser traffic in fiddler logs.

1. I tried by checking the option "Automatically detect settings" (Tools > Winnet Options > LAN Settings)
2. Also checked the option "Decrypt HTTPs Traffic" (Tools - Options - )
3. Also Cleared the "Clear Winnet Cache, Cookies, browser cache, temp files" in system.

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?
I attach my error in the image here, for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN software and firewall clients are common culprits. It’s a known issue, please refer below link,

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-auto-reset-fiddler-when-%27system-proxy-was-changed%27

Answer (score 1):

Some VPN's doesn't allow you to pass traffic for other applications.
If you're professional and using the VPN's provided by Company, ask the company/support team regarding issue. They have their own setup for these type of applications.

Some New VPN's like Z-Scaler will not allow the web traffic to other applications and they're trying to resolve this issue asap. But for temporary solution, they have a kind of setup which we can use to work?

Make sure you tried all the options of fiddler and if it is new VPN, Google it and that VPN may already provided which applications will not work with their VPN's